# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.state')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I keep getting this error when trying to access this.state
None of the solutions I've tried so far worked

**Here's my constructor**

```
export default class Layout extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            bagTitle: 'View Bag'
        }
        this.renderContent = this.renderContent.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <NavigationContainer>
                <Stack.Navigator>
                    <Stack.Screen name='Menu' component={HomeScreen}
                        options={{
                            headerRight: () => (
                                <Ionicons style={iconView.icons} name='ios-list' size={26} color="black" />
                            ),
                        }}
                    />
                </Stack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        );
    };
}
```

**This is where I'm calling the renderContent function**

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const title = 'View Bag'
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
        {/* Bottomsheet View */}

        <BottomSheet
          ref={sheetRef}
          snapPoints={[100, 300, Dimensions.get('window').height - 100]}
          borderRadius={10}
          renderContent={renderContent}
        >
          <Text onPress={showBag} style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', fontSize: 17, fontWeight: '600', textAlign: 'center', position: "absolute", marginTop: 20, width: windowWidth }}>View Bag</Text>
        </BottomSheet>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**This is where I'm trying to access this.state**

```
renderContent = () => (
    <View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
        padding: 16,
        fontSize: 20,
        height: windowHeight,
        width: windowWidth,
        marginBottom: -200
      }}
    >
      <Text onPress={showBag} style={{ fontSize: 17, fontWeight: '600', textAlign: 'center', position: "absolute", marginTop: 20, width: windowWidth }}>{this.state.bagTitle}</Text>
    </View>
);
```

**Keep getting this error**

> undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.state')

Comment: @TopTalent do you know what the problem might be by any chance?

Comment: Did you use `renderContent={this.renderContent}` in `HomeScreen` class?
Or `this.props.renderContent`?

Comment: When I use them, the bottomSheet doesn't show up

Comment: Could you share your project repo? Or create codesandbox.io? Let me take a look.

Comment: Sure here's the repo: https://github.com/Jkurbs/web

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222983/discussion-between-top-talent-and-john).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `showBag` and `renderContent` in `HomeScreen` class

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      bagTitle: 'View Bag'
    }
    this.showBag = this.showBag.bind(this);
    this.renderContent = this.renderContent.bind(this);
  }

  // FUNCTIONS
  showBag = (item) => {
    sheetRef.current.snapTo(1);
    if (item.title !== null) {
      this.setState({
        bagTitle: item.title
      })
      console.log('ITEM: ', item);
    }
  }

  renderContent = () => (
    <View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
        padding: 16,
        fontSize: 20,
        height: windowHeight,
        width: windowWidth,
        marginBottom: -200
      }}
    >
      <Text onPress={this.showBag} style={{ fontSize: 17, fontWeight: '600', textAlign: 'center', position: "absolute", marginTop: 20, width: windowWidth }}>{this.state.bagTitle}</Text>
    </View>
  );

  render() {
    const title = 'View Bag'
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
        {/* Bottomsheet View */}

        <BottomSheet
          ref={sheetRef}
          snapPoints={[100, 300, Dimensions.get('window').height - 100]}
          borderRadius={10}
          renderContent={this.renderContent}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```